# How do I call a variable from another definition in python?

Tags: python

This gives me an error when I run this code 'TypeError: days() missing 1 required positional argument: 'age' I am relatively new to this and not sure what to do! :) Thanks

```
def name():
name= input("Hello, what is your name? ")
age= int(input("Hello, please input your age: "))
choice= int(input("What unit would you like to measure your age in?\n1. Days\n2. Hours\n3. Mins\n4. Seconds\n9. Exit\n"))
if choice == 1:
    days()
elif choice == 2:
    hours()
elif choice == 3:
    mins()
elif choice == 4:
    seconds()
elif choice == 9:
    print("Goodbye!")


def days(age):
    print(name,",please wait so i can calculate how many days you have been alive...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(age*365)

def hours(age):
    print(name,",please wait so i can calculate how many hours you have been alive...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(age*365/24)


def mins(age):
    print(name,",please wait so i can calculate how many minutes you have been alive...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(age*365/24/60)

def seconds(age):
    print(name,",please wait so i can calculate how many seconds you have been alive...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(age*365/24/60/60)

name()
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. I corrected a missing `"` on line 3. I'm on a phone so indentation is something you need to fix

Comment: you're calling your function without an argument it should be `days(age)`

Comment: Thanks sorry i forgot about that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass argument to all your functions.

```
if choice == 1:
    days(age)
elif choice == 2:
    hours(age)
elif choice == 3:
    mins(age)
elif choice == 4:
    seconds(age)
elif choice == 9:
    print("Goodbye!")
```